# jackson dependency build error with stax-api jar

Tags: android, dependencies, jackson, restlet, stax

I making an Android app which communicate with a Google App Engine and to do that I use the `Restlet` API.

My dependencies in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'org.restlet.android:org.restlet:2.2.2'
    compile 'org.restlet.android:org.restlet.ext.jackson:2.2.2'
}
```

Here's the trace after trying to build the project :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
E:\Applications\Android Studio\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex 
--output [projectPath]\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\stax-api-1.0-2-[...].jar
[windowsAccountPath]\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.xml.stream\stax-api\1.0-2\[...]\stax-api-1.0-2.jar

Error Code: 1
Output:
trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/EventFilter.class":
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse).
```

Building without `compile 'org.restlet.android:org.restlet.ext.jackson:2.2.2'` work but obviously I have errors in my code..

I don't know what the stax API is, I don't even use it !

Can someone know how to properly import and use `Restlet` API for Android ?

Comment: This dependency comes with the com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.jar.
I've updated the Android edition of the Restlet Framework in order to remove the transparent serialization/deserialization of XML using Jackson.
The fix will be part of the future 2.3.0, and 2.2.4 releases.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this issue by excluding dependencies causing the issue : -

```
compile('com.fasterxml:jackson-xml-databind:0.6.2'){
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
```

If you necessarily need those, use jar jar to rename class paths to make things work.

> https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/SiriRestClient/wiki
>
> https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/